# woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order not triggered

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'd like to customise the recipient of a new order in WooCommerce. According to the documentation and various examples I can do this like so:

```
function wc_change_admin_new_order_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    global $woocommerce;

//some code
    return $recipient;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'wc_change_admin_new_order_email_recipient', 10, 2);
```

However I cannot get this filter to trigger on my local development machine, nor can I get the site to send order emails even with this code removed.

I have a working local debugger and the code stops at various points in the wc_email class, however it only gets to the get_recipient function when I change the admin email in the backend.

Here is what I have tried:

- turned all other plugins off
- made sure Wordpress, WooCommerce, Theme is up to date
- Some theme files are shown as not up to date, but admin-new-order.php does not show in this list
- admin-new-order.php in overrides folder is identical to WooCommerce version, so I have also tried to remove the override completely
- Lost password sends me an email on my local system (over the Internet), so email delivery is working

Is there a cron job used for delivery of the admin new order email, if so how can I trigger it?

Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue, and I find it hard to believe that "new_order" is only triggered after the order was paid, as there is a filter for specifically that event: woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_invoice_paid. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The order notification email to admin is sent as part of the Payment notification process - in this case Paypal IPN

To test this on a local domain, the best way was to trigger the order email from the orders list in the backend.

The above code works fine.

Comment: Is this actually true? Shouldn't "new_order" be triggered as the order is placed? There are filter hooks pertaining to when orders have been processed, paid etc, such as 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_invoice_paid'

Comment: its a while ago, but I recall testing this with a debugger on a project I was working on then

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Version: **5.2.2**

WooCommerce version: **3.7.0**

To send a static recipient (override default)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'hasan_headers_filter_function', 10, 2);

function hasan_headers_filter_function( $headers, $object ) {
  $headers = 'Test Dealer <rana_imagine@yahoo.com>';
  return $headers;
}
```

To send extra static recipient along with admin

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'hasan_headers_filter_function', 10, 2);

function hasan_headers_filter_function( $headers, $object ) {
  $headers .= 'CC: Test Dealer <rana_imagine@yahoo.com>' . "\r\n";
  return $headers;
}
```

if you only want to send when order is complete

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'hasan_headers_filter_function', 10, 2);

function hasan_headers_filter_function( $headers, $object ) {
  if ($object == 'customer_completed_order') {
    $headers .= 'CC: Test Dealer <rana_imagine@yahoo.com>' . "\r\n";
  }
  return $headers;
}
```